# ECONNRESET error on salesforce API calls at random

Tags: api, integration, limitexception, connection

I am trying to integrate with salesforce and after a few mins-hours some API calls are failing at random

Following is the error captured:

> { Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
> at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (_tls_wrap.js:1095:19)
> at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:203:15)
> at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:111:27) errno: '**ECONNRESET**', code: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }

API calls are working fine after retry with delay of 10-30s. I don't think it is rate limit issue as API calls work fine after only a 10s delay

**EDIT**
Sometimes the error returned is **ECONNREFUSED** & **ETIMEDOUT**